# How to convert a string date to compare with date in database, PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to convert a string sent into a function into a date so that I can compare it with a date field in the database, but it's not working and I can't figure out why.

I've tried this:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('job/DOEIntakeForm/' . $hearingdate); ?>">Download Intake Forms</a>
```

And

```
public function DOEIntakeForm($hearingDate) {
    $newDate = date_format(date_create($hearingDate), 'Y-m-d');
    $query = 'SELECT id, orderdata, reportername, hearing FROM job WHERE jobtypeid = 307 AND hearingtype = 9 AND hearing = ' . $newDate;
    $result = $this->db->query($query)->result();
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); exit;
}
```

And then I tried sending the date in already formatted, like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('job/DOEIntakeForm/' . date('Y-m-d',strtotime($hearingdate))); ?>">Download Intake Forms</a>
```

But I keep getting an empty array for $result. I don't see what I am doing wrong. I have looked up many examples online and they all do it this way, so why is it not working?

If I hard-code the date into the query, everything works fine.

TIA.

EDIT:
When I var_dump $hearingDate, I get C:\###\application\controllers\Job.php:2462:string '2019-03-01' (length=10)

Comment: can you give an example of `$hearingdate`

Comment: I added an example of hearing date in my original question. It is a string that is formatted Y-m-d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use prepared statements, so you will avoid SQL injection and issues like this. You need to put single quotes for the date, so it will look like this `AND hearingtype = 9 AND hearing ='2019-03-01'`:

```
public function DOEIntakeForm($hearingDate) {
    $newDate = date_format(date_create($hearingDate), 'Y-m-d');
    $query = "SELECT id, orderdata, reportername, hearing FROM job WHERE jobtypeid = 307 AND hearingtype = 9 AND hearing = '" . $newDate."'";
    $result = $this->db->query($query)->result();
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); exit;
}
```

See that i changed your ' by ".